# Can Azure App Services have fixed MAC addresses?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I've got an Azure app service that I'd like to use to run some software that requires licensing. The license is provided via a server on our internal network. The issue being finding a way to connect to this server.

The first option is to provide a fixed license that ties to the MAC address. However I don't think this will be possible from an app service, as it does not really have a MAC address? Can I provide a VNI to it and obtain a fixed MAC address that way?

What other options are there? Can the app service be tied to a VNET that can tunnel to the on-premises resource? Should I use a VM with a VNI instead of an app service? Any resources on these kind of problems would be appreciated.

Comment: Any update? Is this issue fixed on your side?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Azure Relay to connect my on-prem service with my app service. Not sure if you have already considered this option.

If your requirement is to establish a connection between your on-prem service and you app service, check out this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VNet Integration with Azure App service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) and [Azure VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways) to connect to on-premise resources. VNet Integration is used only to make outbound calls from your app into your VNet. There are Regional VNet Integration and Gateway-required VNet Integration.

[How regional VNet Integration works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#how-regional-vnet-integration-works)

> Regional VNet Integration works by mounting virtual interfaces with
>   addresses in the delegated subnet. Because the from address is in your
>   VNet, it can access most things in or through your VNet like a VM in
>   your VNet would. The networking implementation is different than
>   running a VM in your VNet. That's why some networking features aren't
>   yet available for this feature.

[How gateway-required VNet Integration works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#how-gateway-required-vnet-integration-works)

> Gateway-required VNet Integration is built on top of point-to-site VPN
>   technology. Point-to-site VPNs limit network access to the virtual
>   machine that hosts the app. Apps are restricted to send traffic out to
>   the internet only through Hybrid Connections or through VNet
>   Integration. When your app is configured with the portal to use
>   gateway-required VNet Integration, a complex negotiation is managed on
>   your behalf to create and assign certificates on the gateway and the
>   application side. The result is that the workers used to host your
>   apps are able to directly connect to the virtual network gateway in
>   the selected VNet.

For more information, you could read this blog---[How to Connect Azure Web Apps To On-Premises](https://www.petri.com/connect-azure-web-apps-premises)

In addition, If you need more control of the application deployment and less scale out or in than the Azure app service. You could host your application on the Azure VM, then set up a VPN gateway in that VNet where Azure VM locate, it allows access to the on-premise resources from your Azure VM as usual in the internal network.